# Please explain these SQL statements

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, dynamic-sql, information-schema

Please explain me the below example

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C 
WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
  AND COLUMN_NAME =('columns_name') INTO @COLUMNS;

SET @table = 'table_name';

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ',@columns,' FROM ', @table);

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
```

Comment: "_Explain me the below_"  Your question is broad can you clarify what you want?

Comment: have you read the manual for each statement you don't understand? Please clarify what exactly is puzzling you.

Comment: Above statements in the question meant, just selecting all the columns of a given table

Comment: generating dynamic sql with all the columns from the given sql

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is all about creating dynamic (*prepared* in MySQL parlance) queries based on the names of columns in a particular table. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is a built-in database with read-only tables describing all the tables in all databases on the MySQL server.

The first query in your sequence retrieves a text string in the local variable `@COLUMNS` with a value like

```
      id,name,value,description
```

for a table named `table_name` with those four columns.

The third one retrieves a string in the local variable `@s` with a value containing a query like

```
      SELECT id,name,value,description FROM table_name
```

The fourth one, `PREPARE`, gets ready to do `EXECUTE stmt`, which runs the query. [You can read about `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

The whole sequence of queries in your question does almost exactly the same thing as `SELECT * FROM table_name`.

There's a defect in your first query. You should add `AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()` to its `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, you may pick up columns from tables named `table_name` in multiple databases.

Comment: I have another question..

i hav source table having 5 columns. i need to create mapping table for source . when we are trying to insert source data to another table with the help of mappng table.We need to write a dynamic query to insert the data to another table.

some times column increases to 7 in source table. we have to change only in the mapping table not in the sql query.. query should dynamically picks the data from source table and load it to target table.